# extract content after pattern matching in linux

Tags: linux, bash, shell, awk

I want to extract some content after a matching pattern from a file.

```
$ cat test
setenv se_boot_opt heap=0x100000 node_type=IB
namedalloc GWUP_FEATURE_MEMORY_BLOCK 0x480000000 0x16093A000
namedprint
setenv se_boot_opt2 heap=0x256000 node_type=AB
```

I need to process the input file line by line. For each line it need to check the following.

1. If the line starts with `setenv` word then it should omit the first 2 words and print/output the remaining content in that line.
2. If the line starts with `namedalloc` then it should replace with `uboot_namedalloc` word.

I want to have only the below lines in my output.

```
heap=0x100000 node_type=IB
uboot_namedalloc GWUP_FEATURE_MEMORY_BLOCK 0x480000000 0x16093A000
namedprint
heap=0x256000 node_type=AB
```

Comment: After matching what pattern? Describing what you want to match helps to eliminate false positives.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `awk` script will do the trick:

```
$ awk '$1=="setenv"{$1=$2="";sub(/ */,"")}$1=="namedalloc"{$1="uboot_"$1}1' file
heap=0x100000 node_type=IB
uboot_namedalloc GWUP_FEATURE_MEMORY_BLOCK 0x480000000 0x16093A000
namedprint
heap=0x256000 node_type=AB
```

Comment: I have updated my answer to meet your new specification. In future please post the question your actually want to ask as it is not fair on users if you change your question to invalidate existing answers. Please read the [**help**](http://stackoverflow.com/help) section, especially on asking and formatting questions. If this solution solves your problem then you should accept this answer (or another answers if a better on comes along) by clicking the tick mark next to it.

Answer (score 1):

give grep a try:

```
grep -o 'heap=.*'
```

exmaple

```
kent$  echo "setenv se_boot_opt1 heap=0x100000 node_type=IB
namedprint
setenv se_boot_opt2 heap=0x256000 node_type=AB"|grep -o 'heap=.*'
heap=0x100000 node_type=IB
heap=0x256000 node_type=AB
```

Comment: You are only using BRE so I would drop the `-P` especially as it limits you to GNU grep.

Comment: @sudo_O you are right, I was thinking of look behind when I typed it, but it was not necessary. thx

Answer (score 1):

```
grep -o 'heap=[^ ]* node_type=[^ ]*' test
heap=0x100000 node_type=IB
heap=0x256000 node_type=AB
```

Answer (score 0):

perl method.

```
echo 'setenv se_boot_opt heap=0x100000 node_type=IB
namedalloc GWUP_FEATURE_MEMORY_BLOCK 0x480000000 0x16093A000
namedprint
setenv se_boot_opt2 heap=0x256000 node_type=AB' | perl -lape 'if (/^setenv/){s/(\w+\s){2}//}elsif(/^namedalloc/){s/namedalloc/uboot_namedalloc/}'
```

Output:

```
heap=0x100000 node_type=IB
uboot_namedalloc GWUP_FEATURE_MEMORY_BLOCK 0x480000000 0x16093A000
namedprint
heap=0x256000 node_type=AB
```

not so elegant, but it works.